# I can't remove "Custom toolbar" from the ribbon in my C# Add in

Tags: c#, excel-2010, add-in

I'm currently developing an excel add in C#, but it show this empty "Custom toolbar" on the ribbon, what i did not create

I checked the xml of the ribbon, but it does not show anything like this:

```
    <code>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="Addin">
                <group id="devGroup" label="Developer" visible="false">
                    <comboBox id="cmbModules" screentip="Select Module" label="Modules" showImage="false" />
                    <button id="btnInstallModule" onAction="btnInstallModule_Click" label="Install" showImage="false" />
                    <button id="btnUninstall" onAction="btnUninstall_Click" label="Uninstall" showImage="false" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
</code>
```

[[image]

Anybody know anything about this issue?

`private void ExcelRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
            cmbModules.Items.Clear();`

```
        foreach (var module in PSAddinModules.ModuleHandler.ModuleList)
        {
            var dropDownItem = this.Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
            dropDownItem.Label = module.Value.Name;
            cmbModules.Items.Add(dropDownItem);
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you expand on the code? Are you using any libraries, if so what

Comment: It is a bit big to expand the whole, but i dont use any library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, caused by the Team Foundation Add-in. 
Tools --> Options --> Add-Ins, Manage COM Add-ins and disabled it there did the trick for me

Comment: Yeah, it works! Only you forgot to mention that this should be done in the Excel (not in the VS).